# Get multiple xml nodes (delimited)

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a xml that is formatted something like this (simplified for readability)

```
<parentItem xmlns:i="http://tempuri.org/1" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/2">
  <ItemA></ItemA>
  <ItemB></ItemB>
  <ItemC xmlns:d2p1="http://tempuri.org/3">
    <d2p1:string>value1</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>value2</d2p1:string>
    <d2p1:string>value3</d2p1:string>
    <!-- .... (0 to many strings here) -->
  </ItemC>
</parentItem>
```

The only think I care about are the values in parentItem > ItemC > string

I would like to get those values delimited by something, such as a comma

**Desired Result: "value1,value2,value3"**

currently I can get one value by doing this:

```
SELECT CAST([QueryXml] as xml).value('(/*:parentItem/*:ItemC/node())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM [opendb].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

Result: "value1"

I can also get all the values like this:

```
SELECT CAST([QueryXml] as xml).value('(/*:ConflictsSearchTermQuery/*:TermItems)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM [opendb].[dbo].[ConflictsSearchTerms]
```

Result: "value1value2value3"

but I'm looking to get a delimited set of values

**Desired Result: "value1,value2,value3"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get multiple values out of XML you need to use [the `nodes()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) of the XML data type.

However, since this method does not return a single, scalar value (but a rowset), you need to call it through `CROSS APPLY`.

```sql
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, CAST('<parentItem xmlns:i="http://tempuri.org/1" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/2">
   <ItemA></ItemA>
   <ItemB></ItemB>
   <ItemC xmlns:d2p1="http://tempuri.org/3">
       <d2p1:string>value1</d2p1:string>
       <d2p1:string>value2</d2p1:string>
       <d2p1:string>value3</d2p1:string>
       <!-- .... (0 to many strings here) -->
   </ItemC>
</parentItem>' AS XML) AS QueryXml
)
SELECT
  t.ID,
  x.node.value('.', 'varchar(100)') AS nodeValue
FROM
  MyTable t
  CROSS APPLY QueryXml.nodes('
    declare namespace i="http://tempuri.org/1";
    declare namespace def="http://tempuri.org/2";
    declare namespace d2p1="http://tempuri.org/3";

    /def:parentItem/def:ItemC/d2p1:string'
  ) x(node)
```

gives you

```
ID          nodeValue
----------- ------------------
1           value1
1           value2
1           value3
```

After that, if you really must, standard techniques for concatenating values in SQL Server apply.

Note that I have properly declared the namespaces in the XQuery instead of using `*`. Namespaces are important, don't ignore them.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully I can just do the concatenation in SSRS.